# What is the meaning of "no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance"?

Tags: ios

My ios application crashes with the following exception:

```
void HandleExceptions(NSException *__strong):875 ERROR: uncaught exception: no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKindOfKind: ColorDecoratorView at path <NSIndexPath: 0x7d843ec0> {length = 3, path = 3 - 0}
```

Can you please tell me what is the meaning of "no UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes instance for -layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKindOfKind"? And where should I look to trouble shoot it?

I have implmenemtned this method:

```
   - (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:(NSString *)decorationViewKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

But I get the following exception when I rotate the screen:

```
uncaught exception: layout attributes for supplementary item at index path (<NSIndexPath: 0x79ef2c80> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}) changed from <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x82e76830> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0x79ebf750> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}); element kind: (ColorDecoratorView); frame = (72 2513; 293.333 252);  to <UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes: 0x79ef9380> index path: (<NSIndexPath: 0x79ef2c80> {length = 2, path = 1 - 0}); element kind: (ColorDecoratorView); frame = (0 825; 1024 -327);  without invalidating the layout
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

are you implementing this medthod ?

`- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:(NSString *)decorationViewKind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

the return value is 
`A layout attributes object containing the information to apply to the decoration view.`

I would say implement this method. something like this
 `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attrs = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes layoutAttributesForDecorationViewOfKind:decorationViewKind withIndexPath:indexPath];
attrs.frame = cgrectmake (x,x,x,x);
return attrs;`

looks like one your cell is asking for some layoutAttributes from the collection view. 
NSIndexPath seems to be [L=3, path = 3];

get the indexPath.row and further investigate in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Thanks. I have implmemented the method you suggested. But I get a new crash when I rotate the simulator from Protait to landscape. I have updated my questions for the crash.